# I cannot enter a second choice in my program's main loop

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner, do-while

This is for AP Computer Science A. I am using classes PhoneBook and PhoneEntry that we already made, to make a program where you can search for a contact, add a contact, and delete a contact. Here is my code for the main program:

```
public class RobertSmithMod10PhoneBook2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Initialize scanner
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Initialize our phone book
        PhoneBook pb = new PhoneBook();
        //Main loop
        int choice;
        do {
            //Prompt for choices
            System.out.println("What would you like to do? Enter 1, 2, or 3");
            System.out.println("1. Search");
            System.out.println("2. Add a contact");
            System.out.println("3. Delete a contact");
            choice = s.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
                //Search
                case 1:
                    //Prompt the user
                    System.out.println("Last Name? ");
                    //Get the last name
                    String lastName = s.next();
                    //Prompt for first name
                    System.out.println("First Name? ");
                    String firstName = s.next();
                    //Boolean value so we can decide to print if no matches were found
                    boolean noneFound = true;
                    //First we will search by all...if none are returned we will cut
                    // to last name
                    boolean goToLastName = true;
                    PhoneEntry[] arr = pb.search(firstName, lastName);
                    for (PhoneEntry phoneEntry : arr) {
                        if (phoneEntry != null) {
                            goToLastName = false;
                            noneFound = false;
                            System.out.println(phoneEntry.getLastName() + ", " + phoneEntry.getFirstName());
                            System.out.println(phoneEntry.getPhone());
                        }
                    }
                    //If we have to go to last name
                    if (goToLastName) {
                        PhoneEntry[] secondArr = pb.searchLastName(lastName);
                        for (PhoneEntry i : secondArr) {
                            if (i != null) {
                                noneFound = false;
                                System.out.println(i.getLastName() + ", " + i.getFirstName());
                                System.out.println(i.getPhone());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //If no matches were found
                    if (noneFound) System.out.println("No matches found. ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //Prompt the user and get the new contact info
                    System.out.println("Last Name? ");
                    lastName = s.next();
                    System.out.println("First Name? ");
                    firstName = s.next();
                    System.out.println("Phone Number? (Format (XXX) XXX-XXXX)");
                    String number = s.nextLine();
                    //Add this contact
                    pb.addContact(firstName, lastName, number);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //Prompt user and get info
                    //Prompt the user and get the new contact info
                    System.out.println("Last Name? ");
                    lastName = s.next();
                    System.out.println("First Name? ");
                    firstName = s.next();
                    //Delete the contact
                    pb.deleteContact(firstName, lastName);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Choice error. ");
                    break;
            }
        } while (choice != 4);
    }
}
```

My first choice is always 2 to add a contact. After I enter a contact the program doesn't quit, but I can't enter another choice. No matter what I enter after that, it does nothing.

I am trying to fix the program where I can repeatedly search, add, or delete a contact ex. I want to add a contact, search for that contact, delete it, then quit the program.

Comment: this might be your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Comment: @Stultuske I don't think it is. I've dealt with that problem before and that doesn't seem to be the issue here. I tried inserting a s.nextInt() after choice and after the switch statement is executed but that didn't work.

Comment: which is understandable, you shouldn't be adding nextInt, since that doesn't read the break neither

Comment: @Stultuske so should I put .nextLine()? If so where should I put it?